# Matlab: 2D smooth curve coordinates and animated

Tags: matlab, plot, coordinates, curve-fitting, spline

I need to plot a 2D smooth curve in Matlab. I have found this

```
npts = 10;

xy = [randn(1,npts); randn(1,npts)];

plot(xy(1,:),xy(2,:),'ro','LineWidth',2);

text(xy(1,:), xy(2,:),[repmat('  ',npts,1), num2str((1:npts)')])

ax = gca;

ax.XTick = [];

ax.YTick = [];

hold on

fnplt(cscvn(xy),'r',2)

hold off
```

This is the kind of curve I am looking for. But I need the exact coordinates of the curve (as many as possible x,y points) and to show the curve in a animated way,controlling the speed. Also, I need to plot on the line a circle or any other object following the trajectory (I need to control the speed the circle follows the line).
thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some of your own code. What is "show curve on an animated way"? I can think of abou 3 or 4 different outputs of that sentence

Comment: Imagine the line is a road. I need to plot a "car" on the line following the road with control of speed. I am not familiar to splines in matlab and I do not know how to get the xy coordinates of the curve. pseudocode: define "road" (done by previous code), get xy coordinates of the road, pos(i)=pos(i-1)+speed where pos is the position on the curve of the "car" , but I need the coordinates of the curve. How can i get them?

Comment: Do you have the splines? show us the splines! Dont show us a random code from the internet but the one you are triying ;)

Comment: Any spline is ok. In fact I have to try different curves. So the procedure define random points + cscvn generates the kind of curve I need; but I need to get the coordinates to plot over the curve the moving "car". Or maybe you can suggest me another procedure or functions to get the same result. thanks for your patiente and time